# Unexpected token, expected ","

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I've got a SyntaxError:

```
Unexpected token, expected "," (1:592)
```

in my `NewPizza.vue` file.

I tried to add `,` to every brace but it didn't solve the error.

Here is my source code:

```
<template>
    <form>
        <h3>Add new pizza:</h3>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-3">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="newPizza.name">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-3">Description</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <textarea type="text" class="form-control" rows="5" v-model="newPizza.description"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <p><strong>Option 1:</strong></p>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-3">Size (")</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="newPizza.options[0].size">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-3">Price</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="newPizza.options[0].price">
            </div>
        </div>

        <p><strong>Option 2:</strong></p>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-3">Size (")</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="newPizza.options[1].size">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-3">Price</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="newPizza.options[1].price">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Add</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            newPizza:{
                'name': 'Eg. Margherita',
                'description': 'Eg. A delicious tomato based pizza topped with mozzarella',
                'options': [{
                    'size': 9,
                    'price': 6.95
                }, {
                    'size': 12,
                    'price': 10.95
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

what should I do?

In my opinion, I think the template part doesn't have any problem.
But when I add `v-model` directive to every `input` tag, the code throws the error.

[image: Error screen image]

Comment: Which line is line 592?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code you've posted. Did you use copy-and-paste or did you re-type any part of it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue is you are facing - I got it to work using this psuedo code (I didn't change anything, just put it in template string format and wrapped it in a new Vue instance)..

https://jsfiddle.net/mL7ey3f9/

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="app">
  <app-pizza></app-pizza>
</div>
```

Vue Instance:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

Component (template string flavor, for simplicity):

```
/** Added globally, which you should prob change **/
Vue.component('app-pizza', {
  data() {
    return {
      newPizza: {
        'name': 'Eg. Margherita',
        'description': 'Eg. A delicious tomato based pizza topped with mozzarella',
        'options': [{
          'size': 9,
          'price': 6.95
        }, {
          'size': 12,
          'price': 10.95
        }]
      }
    }
  },
  template: `
  <form>
    <h3>Add new pizza:</h3>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-3">Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="newPizza.name">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-3">Description</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control" rows="5" v-model="newPizza.description"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>

    <p><strong>Option 1:</strong></p>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-3">Size (")</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="newPizza.options[0].size">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-3">Price</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="newPizza.options[0].price">
      </div>
    </div>

    <p><strong>Option 2:</strong></p>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-3">Size (")</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="newPizza.options[1].size">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-3">Price</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="newPizza.options[1].price">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Add</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  `
});
```